# Javascript decoding unicode returns `undefined`

Tags: javascript, json, unicode

I have this two different unicodes in my .Json file:

```
\u30a2\u30eb\u30d0
\u0410\u043d\u0433\u0438\u043b\u044c\u044f
```

Javascript code uses `const data = require('./countries.json');` to access this .Json file and extract this values. But, it can only decode second one, for the first one it returns `undefined` error.
Can anyone explain me why?

Comment: how do you decode the strings? They are std unicode

Comment: Both these values are in the same file? Because if parse them separately using `JSON.parse()` it works as expected: `const data = \`{"mystring": "\u30a2\u30eb\u30d0"}\`;
const data2 = \`{"mystring": "\u0410\u043d\u0433\u0438\u043b\u044c\u044f"}\`;
const test = JSON.parse(data);
const test2 = JSON.parse(data2);
console.log(test);
console.log(test2);`. Resulting in the output `{ mystring: 'アルバ' }
{ mystring: 'Ангилья' }`

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi that's the problem. I never used decoding in this project. For the second unicode it decodes it normally, but for the first one it says `ReferenceError: アングィラ is not defined`.  What is the difference between them?

Comment: @Mushroomator they are in the same file. I also tried separately and it worked. But how do I make them work together?

Comment: @Mushroomator and I am using require function, to read whole .json file. The require function is mentioned in the question.

Comment: You do notice though that the reference error is for `アングィラ` (unicode `\u30A2\u30F3\u30B0\u30A3\u30E9`) as this key does not seem to exist. But the values you have given us are `アルバ` (`\u30a2\u30eb\u30d0`) and `Ангилья` (`\u0410\u043d\u0433\u0438\u043b\u044c\u044f`), so different values. So the value you are looking for might actually not exist in the json. I am assuming you are using these values as properties of course, not as values.

Comment: @Mushroomator    `"official": "\u30a2\u30eb\u30d0"` this is the key for `アングィラ`. As you see it does exist. The same goes for `"common" : "\u0410\u043d\u0433\u0438\u043b\u044c\u044f"`. Th first is returning an error, while second one decodes and return the official name `Ангилья`.

Comment: `ReferenceError: アングィラ is not defined` sounds like a string is missing quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you access those values, but I've recreated your scenario and it does work like expected.

Here my `values.json`

```json
{
  "official": "\u30a2\u30eb\u30d0",
  "common": "\u0410\u043d\u0433\u0438\u043b\u044c\u044f"
}
```

Here my Node code

```js
const values = require("./values.json");
console.log(values.common);
console.log(values.official);
```

Expected output:

```
Ангилья
アルバ
```

I can only guess that you are trying to access a value with a key that does not exist or you are missing quotes.

Comment: https://github.com/TheRadioDept/technical-question/blob/main/countries.json This is a `json file` that I also uploaded on github. If you look at it, you can see that everything is fine from the syntax pov. Only `translations` like `jpn` are not defined, others are decoded fine.

Comment: You have this line here `data.map(point => point.translations[enteredKey].official)`. This will return `undefined` for languages where there is no japanese translation as the key `jpn` does not exist. You need to check for this and it will work like this `data.map(point => point.translations[enteredKey] ? point.translations[enteredKey].official: \`No translation for ${enteredKey}.\`)`. Another note. If you need to remove duplicates just use a [`Set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) straight away as it will do the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: So how can I modify my code for it to work? Or can you explain in details why it isn't working now please?

Comment: Replace `data.map(point => point.translations[enteredKey].official)` with this `data.map(point => point.translations[enteredKey] ? point.translations[enteredKey].official: \`No translation for ${enteredKey}.\`)` and it will work. The difference is that I check whether a japanese (or any other) translation  exists by using `point.translation[enteredKey] ?`. A translation exists when the key in the object exists. If it does exist I return that value, that's the code after the `?`. If it does not, I return e.g. for `enteredKey = "jpn"`  `No translation for jpn`. That's the code after `:`

Comment: Thank you so much! So the problem was that key wasn't existing? But how is that possible? It is defined like any other key, like `rus`. Sorry, I am new at it and do not understand it much.

Comment: Yes, it does exist for most objects but not for all. Look at your JSON in VsCode or so and search for `Curaçao` (item with index 55, so you can also get it using `data[55]`) and look at the translations there. You will see that there is no japanese translation. That's when the error occurred. And you actually have another error. `enteredKey` is an array so you need to access it using `enteredKey[0]` to get the variable passed to the command line. And you should check the length of `enteredKey` or `process.argv` to handle malformed input.

Comment: But I am using it without `enteredKey[0]` and it works normal. Where exactly should I change it?

Comment: Try to run it with multiple arguments and it will fail. So with `node main.js jpn test` it will not work.